# A question about extending vector bundles from formal neighborhood to a coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves, formal-schemes

I have a question which probably is very straightforward but because of my lack of knowledge of formal schemes I'm asking it here. Let's assume we have a vector bundle $E$ on the formal completion $X_Z$ of a scheme $X$ along a closed subscheme $Z$. We know there is a coherent sheaf that extends $E$ on each affine. Does it follow that we can extend $E$ to a coherent sheaf?

Some of my thoughts: Let's assume for simplicity we are working with an affine chart consisting of two affines on $X$ this induces an affine chart on the formal completion too. Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be the restriction of $E$ to each of them and $M_1$, $M_2$ be their coherent extensions. Restriction of $E$ to the intersection of two chart is denoted by $E_{12}$. The vector bundle $E$ fits into a short exact sequence on $X_Z$:
$$0\rightarrow E \rightarrow E_1\oplus E_2 \rightarrow E_{12}\rightarrow 0 \hspace{1cm}(1)$$
By the definition of gluing vector bundles. I was thinking whether it is possible (or when it is possible) to define pushforward of $E_{12}$ from the formal completion in the intersection of two affines to the intersection of two affines?
If we can define a pushforward that is a coherent sheaf denoted by $i_*E_{12}$. Then we have a morphism $M_1\oplus M_2 \rightarrow i_*(E_{12})$ that restricts on the formal completion to the surjection $E_1\oplus E_2 \rightarrow E_{12}$. Taking  the kernel $0\rightarrow \text{kernel} \rightarrow M_1\oplus M_2 \rightarrow i_*(E_{12})$ and using the fact that restricting to formal completion is exact we get the exact sequence (1). So $\text{kernel}$ will be extending $E$.

Comment: Take $E=\mathcal{O}_{X_Z}$, $M=\mathcal{O}_X$. Then (in your final sentence) you're asking if every closed formal subscheme of $X_Z$ extends to a closed subscheme of $X$. This is not true, for example $X=\mathbf{A}^2$, $Z=$ origin, then $X_Z= \operatorname{Spf} k[[X, Y]]$. Take $E$ to be the ideal generated by $X - \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n Y^n$ where $\sum a_n Y^n$ is a transcendental function, e.g. $\sum_{n\geq 1} Y^n/n! =\exp Y - 1$ if $k$ contains $\mathbf{Q}$.